# Entity Framework filter nav property with Self Tracking Entities

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-4, bindingsource, self-tracking-entities

I'm using Self Tracking Entities and have a scenario where I have an entity that represents a table that we'll call table A. A is a parent to another table B which is also represented as an entity. On my WinForm I have 3 different binding sources that each represent different types of records from table B but all are children of table A. So what I want to accomplish is use the navigation property for entity/table B to set each binding source

e.g.

```
bindingSource1.DataSource = A.B.Where(some condition); 
bindingSource2.DataSource = A.B.Where(some other condition);
bindingSource3.DataSource = A.B.Where(another condition);
```

Ideally, the DataSource for each binding source would be of type TrackableCollection so when I save A, all changes to the 3 filtered instances of B are also saved.

I've tried some different options for this but haven't had any luck so I'm hoping someone else has encountered this same scenario.

Thanks!